# php i want to add an update button to each row in table that when clicked will automatically change the status pending to approved.

Tags: php, ajax, crud

So, I have selected a table WHERE status is = 'pending'
and I add edit and delete button to each row
I want to do is when I clicked the edit button it will automatically update 
the column status to ='approved'. 
So basically I want it to update just by clicking the edit button because column status has only 2 values. Pending and Approved.

This is my code

```
<?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "lms");  
$query = "select p.id, 
p.empno,fname,lname,loan,amount,amortization,term,dateapplied,dateupdated 
FROM application p INNER JOIN accounts a ON p.empno = a.empno WHERE p.status 
=  'pending'";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
?>       
<div class="container" style="width:1000px;">    

<div class="table-responsive">
<br />
<div id="employee_table">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<th>Transaction No</th>  
<th>Name</th>  
<th>Employee No</th>  
<th>Type</th>
<th >Amount</th>
<th >Terms</th>
<th>Amortization</th>          
<th>Date</th>
<th colspan = "2" width="7%">Approved</th>
</tr>
<?php
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["fname"]." ".$row["lname"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["empno"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["loan"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo number_format($row["amount"],2); ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["term"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["amortization"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["dateapplied"]; ?></td>
   <td><input type="button" name="update" value="YES" id="<?php echo 
   $row["id"]; ?>" /></td>
   <td><input type="button" name="del" value="NO" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; 
    ?>"  /></td>
  </tr>
<?php
  }
  ?>
 </table>
```

What should I do next? And also I need to update EACH row.

Comment: You want to update the status of html table column on ajax success?

Comment: uhm anything that can work. Ajax or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to your buttons:

```
<input type="button" name="del" class="editbtn" value="NO" id="<?php echo $row["id"];
```

and call ajax by class name and get current button id by this.id:

```
$(".editbtn").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    $.ajax({url: "test.php?id="+id, success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
```

Comment: So div1 is? and the test.php?

Comment: test.php is file that get your id and update the table and return the result you setted for it. div1 is section you want to be updated for example show the message or show the given result from test.php

Comment: okay ill try. last question for now that this.id?  will i replace the this with the button name?

Comment: no , "this" not to be changed. it means current section i'm working on.

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE application SET status='approved' where id = ; What should i use in where clause?

Comment: because without the where clause it keeps on updating all the data.

Comment: is your id setted correctly in this section:      <td><input type="button" name="del" value="NO" id="<?php echo $row["id"];  do you add class to your code? pleas test  the js code called after click or not

Comment: it setted correctly and its functioning now but my problem is what should i put on my where clause because when i clicked ok button it updates all the data in table

Comment: If you can get the id of row in js (with "this.id") it means you can pass the id through the ajax url ("test.php?id="+id). in "test.php" file first get the id from url and then add the id in your query ( update .... where (id= $_GEt['id']) )

Comment: Undefined index id